# Implicit Partial Differentiation - Which variables are held constant?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Find $x_u$ and $y_u$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ where $u = x^2-y^2$ and $v = x^2 - y$.

($x_u$ means $\partial x/\partial u$)

I need some help understanding which variables are held constant when these two equations are implicitly differentiated with respect to $u$. Why is $\partial y/\partial u$ not equal to 0 but $\partial v/\partial u$ is equal to 0.

Rearranging, I can get $v - u = y^2 - y$ and $(x^2-v)^2=x^2-u$. Then I have no trouble thinking of $x$ and $y$ as implicitly defined functions of $u$ and $v$ and solving.

The materials that I am using implicitly differentiate to get: $1 = 2xx_u - 2yy_u$ and $0 = 2xx_u - y_u$.

I would like to understand what's wrong with the following reasoning: "$x^2 = y^2 + u$ so $x$ is an implicitly defined function of $y$ and $u$. Taking the partial derivative w.r.t. $u$, y is held constant. Therefore, $1 = 2xx_u$."

Comment: It is implicitly understood in the statement that $(x,y)$ is an independent pair, and so is $(u,v)$. Both equations show how $u$ and $v$ depend on $x$ and $y$, but both do so independent of the other, i.e. $u$ depends on $x$ and $y$, but not $v$. Therefore, $u_v=v_u=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. That makes sense. Just to clarify, are you saying that the context of the question indicates that $x$ is not a function of $y$ and $u$? Rather $x$ and $y$ are independent. $x$ and $y$ are functions of $u$ and $v$, so $v$ is held constant when differentiating w.r.t  $u$.

Comment: Yes, exactly that.  I know it is not formal at all, but such a straightforward statement is most likely making such an assumption.